# How to filter elements and then set condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

First want to filter by class and then change class name  :

```
  <div class="root">
    <div class="col-8 catA filter"></div>        
    <div class="col-4 catB filter"></div>        
    <div class="col-8 catA filter"></div>                
    <div class="col-4 catB filter"></div>                
    <div class="col-8 catA filter"></div>                
    <div class="col-4 catB filter"></div>                
  </div>
```

**I want to filter elements by class name "catB" and set condition :**

```
var myFilterData = $('.filter').filter('.catB');
```

**My condition will be like this :**

```
if (myFilterData.index == even) {
//add New class
}
```

> **Is it possible using jquery filter() method ?**

Comment: I think you are filter item on click?

Comment: Yes , filter item on click

Comment: The divs are clickable? And ````<div class="col-4 catB filter"></div>```` triggers a filter to ````catB````? Do I get it right?

Comment: Yes triggers catB .
and same time I want to replace the class name "col-4" to "col-8"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
myFilterData.each(function(index) {
    if (! (index % 2)) $(this)
        .addClass("newClass")
        // .removeClass("catB") // Not sure if you also want this
    ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below solution.You can add or remove the class according to your condition.

```
var myFilterData = $('.filter').filter('.catB');

if (yourcondition == true) {
myFilterData.addClass("newClass");

  // myFilterData.removeClass("catB")  For removing the class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data id in each div and get data id

```
<div class="root">
<div class="col-8 filter" data-id="catA"></div>        
<div class="col-4 filter" data-id="catB"></div>        
<div class="col-8 filter" data-id="catA"></div>                
<div class="col-4 filter" data-id="catB"></div>                
<div class="col-8 filter" data-id="catA"></div>                
<div class="col-4 filter" data-id="catB"></div>                
</div>

<script>
$('.filter').on('click', function(){
   var myFilterData = $(this).data('id')
})
</script>
```

Comment: My query is not like this.
I would like to add new class after filtering all elements.
$('.filter').filter('.catB').css('background', 'red');

but I wnat to change the class name also by checking index number of elements

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to filter all the divs with catB class evenly and change the class accordingly. Try this in your click handler
$('.filter.catB:even').removeClass('col-4').addClass('col-8');

Answer (score 0):

Please check it, this way you can update classes

```html
<div class="root">
    <div class="col-8 catA filter"></div>        
    <div class="col-4 catB filter"></div>        
    <div class="col-8 catA filter"></div>                
    <div class="col-4 catB filter"></div>                
    <div class="col-8 catA filter"></div>                
    <div class="col-4 catB filter"></div>                
  </div>

<script>
document.querySelector('.root').addEventListener('click', function(event){
   event.target.classList.remove('col-4');
   event.target.classList.add('col-8');
});
</script>
```